# Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml];

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have created a maven-spring-hibernate project. 
I deployed the project to tomcat server. I am getting the below exception when hitting the URL in browser.

```
**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml];
```

The nested exception is:

```
org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class** org.springframework.transaction.config.JtaTransactionManagerBeanDefinitionParser
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please suggest how this can be fixed.

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
 xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.contact" />

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>


<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />


<bean id="dataSource"

    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"

    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"

    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"

    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


<bean id="sessionFactory"

    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>

            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

        </props>
    </property>

</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
</beans
```

**Web.xml**

```
<display-name>Spring3-Hibernate</display-name> 
   <welcome-file-list> 
      <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> 
   </welcome-file-list> 
<servlet> 
   <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name> 
   <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class> 
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
   <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name> 
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: this is web.xml:-


<display-name>Spring3-Hibernate</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Could you please edit your question with your spring-servlet.xml and web.xml.

Comment: What is the code of your spring-servlet.xml?

Comment: Looks like you are missing dependent classes in the classpath.  See the top of your stack trace, it mentions unable to load a class.  Looks like `org.springframework.transaction.config.JtaTransactionManagerBeanDefinitionParser` is missing.

Comment: Is it your full code for spring-servlet.xml? If it is then you are missing required namespaces in it.

Comment: <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>

Comment: post your full spring configurations with all namespaces. seems like issue with your namespaces.

Comment: Pasted the spring-servlet.xml file in answers

Comment: Look at the exception trace `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class** org.springframework.transaction.config.JtaTransactionManagerBeanDefinitionParser` have you included required depedencies in pom.xml

Comment: why you have posted spring configuration file as a answer, there is a option to edit your question, you can edit it in question part itself.

Comment: It seems you are missing spring-tx.jar, make sure that it is there in your classpath and same configured in the pom file.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error, while i typed wrong name of dependent bean's property in spring-servlet.xml file.

> Configuration problem: unexpected failure during bean definition
> parsing offending resource ,ServletContext resource
> [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]

and resolved the error with  checking and typing correct dependent beans name and property names.
**Advice** : if you get above error check and match the correct dependent beans and their property names to solve this error.